# Flask/wsgi - Permission Denied while writing log files or touching random files

Tags: python, apache, logging, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm writing a very simple Flask program that logs POST payload. It was working well in debug, so I wired it up to apache. Now I'm getting 
"IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:" when attempting to log anywhere but /tmp.

I'm running apache v2.4.6 and wsgi v3.4 on RHEL 7.x. 
Here's my stuff:

vhost file:

```html
Listen *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName www.test.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error2.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access2.log combined

    # didn't work
    #<Directory />
    #    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    #    AllowOverride All
    #    Require all granted
    #</Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess csplogger user=apache group=apache threads=5
    WSGIProcessGroup csplogger
    WSGIScriptAlias /report-to /var/www/FLASKAPPS/csplogger/csplogger.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

csplogger.wsgi file:

```html
#!/bin/python
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FLASKAPPS/")

from csplogger import app as application
```

And the python:

```js
from flask import Flask, request
import json
import os
import logging
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

if not app.debug:

    logdir = '/opt/logs/'

    file_handler = FileHandler('/tmp/access.log')
    #file_handler = FileHandler(logdir + 'access.log')
    #file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(logdir + 'access.log', maxBytes=20000000, backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'))

    logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logging.getLogger('werkzeug').addHandler(file_handler)

    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    # adding some debug
    app.logger.info(os.environ)
    app.logger.info(os.path.dirname(logdir).format())
    app.logger.info(os.listdir(logdir))

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():

    if request.method != 'POST':
        app.logger.info('GET testing'.format())
        return ('not a post\n', 200)
    else:
        data = request.get_json()
        app.logger.info(json.dumps(data))
        return ('', 204)

if __name__ =='__main__':

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False)
```

/opt/logs is the intended log destination. It's chown'd apache:apache (which is my apache user/group) and perm'd wide open. I know the python app can find these directories because I'm listing the contents and logging it (when logging to /tmp/access.log) as part of debugging. I mentioned this is RHEL but I didn't mention that SELinux is disabled.

Long story short, I can see files in a directory, both of which are permed 777 and owned by the apache user, but I can't write those log files.

Thanks for your time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a bad question?  It it something too simple to be worth answering?  Or has nobody else seen it?

Comment: any chance resolving it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the way I resolved it might not have been the direct solution to this, but it worked for me.

Instead of configuring `app.logger`, I directly created the logger from logging package:

```
if not app.debug:

    logdir = '/opt/logs/'

    file_handler = FileHandler('/tmp/access.log')
    #file_handler = FileHandler(logdir + 'access.log')
    #file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(logdir + 'access.log', maxBytes=20000000, backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'))

    logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logging.getLogger('werkzeug').addHandler(file_handler)

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) 

    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # adding some debug
    logger.info(os.environ)
    logger.info(os.path.dirname(logdir).format())
    logger.info(os.listdir(logdir))
```

The actual solution that would keep `app.logger` in place might be related to this too. Something like: `app.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` but I haven't tried it myself.